Managing Memory Cache Invalidation Across Separate Containers for FPM and Supervisor Workers
We are using FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) and Nginx in our setup, along with a memory repository to reduce the number of hits to Redis. However, we are encountering an issue where some foreach loops process many identical pieces of data, such as airline IATA codes in flights. For instance, if there are 100 items with the same IATA code, our system currently performs 100 separate hits to retrieve this data.
This approach works fine with FPM but presents challenges in the Supervisor worker container. We have observers set up to delete cache and memory keys after updating the database. The issue arises because the worker runs in a different container from the application, so memory keys are not deleted until the listener for ForgetMemoryCache is dispatched to the worker.
Given this setup, do you think it's wise to proceed with this approach? What are your thoughts?

You can use Redis to implement a distributed lock; or if you have a worker, you can farm out the remote data fetch to the worker and let that ensure the task doesn't run multiple times.  I'd avoid supervisord given the choice, but that's probably not directly related to your specific problem.

I REALLY like this question, but with the way it's set up you may get opinions vs facts and citations. I'm going to follow this one though, as I think the nature of the question itself could be useful for me later. I would suggest editing your question to highlight a specific problem you're running into, what you've tried, and the specific behavior you're seeing that's giving you trouble.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
